# Update Magento to specific version (not latest)

Tags: magento, upgrade

I want to update a Magento 1.4.2.0 to 1.6.x.y. instead of the latest version 1.7.x.y

There are many articles on how to update a Magento installation to the latest version, but that´s not what I want. There are some forum threads where people are asking how to update to a specific version, but those all don´t sport a solution.

It seems like it is only possible to unpack the tar.gz of the specific version, but it is not possible to use the command line tool, i.e.

```
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
./mage upgrade-all --force
```

Is there a way to use the command line tool to update to a specific version?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175251/upgrade-magento-to-a-specific-version-not-the-latest-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two different ways of handling this, 1) Manually...**

From my experience, what you end up doing is scrapping Magento Connect (which often is the source of all evil, when you've had it do partial upgrades two or three times in a row), downloading the whole package [from the download archive](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download) (you have all the versions available from there on the Release Archives tab), unzipping them to a directory and then either on the server, copying them into your Magento root directory or from a remote workstation, ftp/scp uploading them to the server Magento root directory.

**If you're serious about running Magento, you will have a development server that you do this to several times to find out where all the upgrade breakages are so you can weed out busted templates, detect forgotten core modifications, curse third party modules that don't survive, etc.** It's really important to do this if you're depending on that e-commerce site for your income as intense suckage occurs when you aren't ready and sink the live site.

If you've modularized all your module overrides, created your own skin folders and custom template or used a well written template from a developer, it truly is just simply dumping the new version files on top of the old version files and overwriting everything (**only after** disabling all Magento caching and the compiler if you were using it and manually deleting all var/cache--? folders).

If, however, you've modified any of the files you are overwriting, you are in a world of hurt because you didn't do things properly.

Also, you have to deal with upgrading third party modules to work with the new version.

Then before committing the live site, backup all Magento application files and do a database dump.

**2) Or use the command line tool as follows...**

**Since the original question was, "can you use the command line tool?" yes you can.** Once you have the file saved [from the download archive](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download), use the following:

```
./mage install-file /home/login-name/path-to-download-file/magento-1.5.x.x.tgz
```

I've also used this on various module packages to inspect the contents. The mage command has a download only, download the package file, inspect the contents. If you like what it does, install it.

Comment: One of the issues that using ./mage has is it will not necessarily notify you if files cannot be overwritten. Usually, your ftp/scp client will complain loudly and you will avert having a weird half-working installation composed of the previous version and the installer version. The installer's previous incarnation (./pear) was notorious for missing package bits. The release packages from the downloads page are necessarily, totally complete and using them bypasses all this nonsense. **Using ./mage, however; is much easier** so use what you're comfortable with.

Comment: So, basically option 2 is the same as option 1. I wanted to avoid searching/downloading the specific version manually to have it a little bit more convenient. In your experience option 1 is the way that works best (if you pay attention to the things you mentioned)?

Comment: Will this `./mage install-file /home/login-name/path-to-download-file/magento-1.7.0.2.tgz` work to upgrade the database too? Will it access the local.xml database access to accomplish that?

Comment: @ButtleButkus - It installs the full Magento codebase for that version. The database gets updated the first time you try to access Magento which is the standard sequence. Install the new version, trip the installers by trying to access the admin panel or front end, outwait the hesitate and pray it doesn't stop on a db conversion issue or throw an exception error.

Comment: There are no tgz downloads anymore (just zip), i unpacked and tar czf, but that did not help. Answer could use a freshup.

Comment: Do I need to follow the same steps to update my magento from 1.9.2 to 1.9.3.2 ?