# Upgrade Magento to a specific version (not the latest version)

Tags: magento, upgrade

I know that I can upgrade to the latest version with the following command:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

Is there a way to set a different package name instead of Mage_All_Latest. I have tried also to install via ./mage install-file but I got an error that the file was not valid.

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083556/update-magento-to-specific-version-not-latest

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I have read this answer already. My problem is that ./mage install-file /home/login-name/path-to-download-file/magento-1.5.x.x.tgz doesn't work - it responds with an error that the archive can't be read. I would like to use the ./mage tool, because the upgrade to the last version basically works.

Answer (score 1):

Mage install is used to install packages, so this does not work.

```
./mage install-file /path/to/full/mage/release
```

There does not seem to be a version argument for ./mage install, so I believe you need install each package separately.

You can download package archives from here: http://ext.topmage.com/.

Find your version http://ext.topmage.com/extensions/8a/a0/Mage_All_Latest/

Open the package.xml file and see what package dependencies are required.

e.g.

```
<package>
    <name>Mage_Core_Modules</name>
    <channel>community</channel>
    <min>1.9.2.2</min>
    <max>1.9.2.2</max>
</package>
```

Then download each package for your version from http://ext.topmage.com/ somewhere locally on your system e.g. /usr/local/src

Then run the following for each package.

```
$ ./mage install-file /usr/local/src/Mage_Core_Modules-1.9.2.2.tgz --force
```

I also had to delete ./pkginfo/Mage_All_Latest.txt and hack ./downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Validator.php to prevent file 'already exists' error.